# select mode mapping issue

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I’ve installed the [Snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) Vim plugin. Suppose I’m editing a `C` file. When I type `if<tab>` in insert mode, the text expands to

```
if (/* condition */)
{

}
```

and now, I’m in `select` mode (indicated in the status line by `--select--`).

I have a mapping in my `~/.vimrc`: `snoremap <c-f> <bs>`, which means I want to use Ctrl-f to delete the text when I’m in select mode.

However, when I type `<c-f>` to delete the text, the text is deleted as expected, but I am dropped into normal mode instead of insert mode as I want.

So, is anyone able to figure this out?

And more—add this mappping:

```
vnoremap <c-f> <bs>
```

`<c-f>` doesn't work at all. Please help with this also.

Answer (score 0):

The help for select mode (`:help Select-mode`) says:

> `Printable characters, <NL> and <CR> cause the selection to be deleted, and
>     Vim enters Insert mode.  The typed character is inserted.`

I don’t see any other case where a command in select mode ends by entering insert mode (although of course I could be missing something).

So this *could* be a peculiarity of the plugin, but it also could just be how select mode handles commands. In the meantime, you can add `i` to the end of your `<c-f>` mapping:

```
snoremap <c-f> <bs>i
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i am using your mapping to work around it now.